# No SSH access after accidentally denied ssh in ufw/iptables on Snappy Ubuntu Core

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewall, docker, ubuntu-core

I´m running `Snappy Ubuntu Core 18.04` on Intel Nuc, located on other location then where I live permanently.

Now I have accidentally denied SSH in `iptables` with use of `ufw` and SSH connection is not possible anymore and I get error `ssh: connect to host mydomain.com port 22: Operation timed out`

1. Are there any options to fix the issue remotely?
2. Is it possible on some way to do a fix by using Docker container running on Nuc? I have Web Access to an Docker management tool, which I can use to spin up new containers and execute commands. But then I need to get access to host commands such as `iptable`, `ufw` and `reboot`
3. Are there any options to fix the issue when I´m on site? With other words, can I get access to Ubuntu Core without using SSH when on site?

Comment: Use the command `sudo ufw status numbered` to find out the number of the offending rule. Use `sudo ufw delete 999` if the offending rule is numbered 999.

Comment: @user68186: Yes, I do have mouse, keyboard and monitor attached to Nuc. But I can´t remember if I will still need to SSH to use the OS, or if I get access without SSH.

Comment: Be aware of that we are talking about Ubuntu Core here, which has more restriction then classic Ubuntu

Comment: I read a bit about Ubuntu Core. You should be able to access the OS locally without `ssh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a monitor, keyboard and mouse connected to your NUC you can log into it directly and use the commands mentioned in user68186's comment to remove the offending rule.

```
sudo ufw status numbered
sudo ufw delete [offending rule number]
```

Logging directly into the machine itself does not require SSH access. SSH is only used when trying to access the computer remotely over network (hence why firewall affects it).

NOTE: Enabling UFW will block incoming SSH connections by default. If there are no rules listed using the `sudo ufw status` command, or none that explicitly block port 22 (SSH) then use one of the commands below to allow SSH through your firewall.

To allow any PC to connect:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

To allow a specific PC to connect: (Requires the PC you want to allow to have a static IP.)

```
sudo ufw allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX to any port 22 proto tcp
```

where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the IP of the PC you want to allow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats good news! Then I´m saved! I´m also looking into solution remotely through Docker container, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681996/access-host-iptables-and-ufw-from-privileged-docker-container

Comment: Glad I could help. I use SSH a lot, but unfortunately I've never used Docker myself so I can't help you with that I'm afraid. I'm sure the lovely community on here can help you out though.